# React .play() error Uncaught (in promise)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Attempting to play a local mp3, the console returns errors:

```
Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.
    at S (index.js:1)
    at V (index.js:1)
    at index.js:1
    at index.js:1
    at a (index.js:1)

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
```

I've tried moving the sound file into both source and public folder, with the same error each time.

The .play() is being called from a component, and works fine when the Audio source is an external link, just not for my local file.

Any pointers appreciated!